# client id not found in the registry - OLE Open XSLX documents error

Tags: java, swt, jface, ole

When I want to display an EXCEL file by SWT OleClient I get following error:

```
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
File openFile = new File("D:\\eDefterKutuphanesi\\eDefter\\excel.xlsx");
OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
OleClientSite  site2 = new OleClientSite(frame,SWT.NONE,"D:\\test.xlsx");
```

Error Message :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Class ID not found in registry 
   at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(OLE.java:317) 
   at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(OLE.java:283) 
   at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite.<init>(OleClientSite.java:226) 
   at infina.accounting.reports.views.ExcelDonusturView.main(ExcelDonusturView.java:438)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Excel.Sheet", new File("D:\\test.xlsx"));
```

You are passing `"D:\\test.xlsx"` as third parameter which should be the `progId` which is `"Excel.Sheet"` for an excel.

Also make sure you have Microsoft Excel installed on your machine. 
**`Class ID not found in registry`** is indicating that the required application is missing.

Comment: Same error Flavio. It still says Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Class ID not found in registry

Comment: Do you have Excel installed on the machine you are running the program?

Comment: I have LibreOffice flavio.It could be the problem? Even I was thinking about it, installing Microsoft Office would prevent this error ?

Comment: Yes, it could be. LibreOffice has not the same OLE support than Excel. I think it has some OLE/COM interfaces supported (I have used them on its predecessor, StarOffice), but I doubt that you can use it in an OleClient And you should use the proper ProgID for LibreOffice.

Comment: "Class ID not found in registry" is saying that the required application is not found, so yes you need Microsoft Office. You could search for the ProgId of LibreOffice and pass it instead of `"Excel.Sheet"`.